# Existence of a non-trivial zero curve

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

Consider the annular region $\mathcal{A} := \{(r,\theta) \in \mathbb{R}^2 :  1 \leq r \leq 2\}$. Suppose that $f: \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function satisfying $f|_{r=1} <0$ and $f|_{r=2} > 0$. Also assume that the zero set of $f$ is a collection of smooth curves. Is it true that there is a component of $\{f=0\}$ which winds around the origin?

*Comment*: Continuity of $f$ implies that on any curve connecting the outer boundary of $\mathcal{A}$ to its inner boundary, there is a zero of $f$. But merely this observation does not imply the existence of a zero curve which winds around the origin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary of the connected component of $\{a \in \mathscr A: f(a) < 0\}$ containing $\{r=1\}$ is a curve that winds around the origin.